# Lomuto Parition Quicksort RecursionError

Tags: python, recursion, quicksort

I'm trying to add a feature to my quicksort implementation to count the number of swaps and comparisons made. It was working fine until I added the code to count swaps/comps and now I'm getting a RecursionError. Can anyone help me understand what's going on? Many thanks!

```
def partition(arr, low, high):
    
    # pivot
    pivot = arr[high]
    comp = 0
    swap = 0
    
    # Index of smaller element
    i = (low - 1)
    for j in range(low, high):
        comp+=1
        # If current element is smaller than or
        # equal to pivot
        if (arr[j] <= pivot):
            # increment index of smaller element
            i += 1
            arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
            swap+=1
    arr[i + 1], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[i + 1]
    swap+=1
    return (comp, swap, i + 1)

def quicksort(A, lo, hi):
  if lo >= 0 and hi >= 0 and lo < hi:
    (comp, swap, p) = partition(A, lo, hi)
    # get the number of comps and swaps on the left and right sides
    (lcomp, lswap) = quicksort(A, lo, p)
    (rcomp, rswap) = quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)
    # return the combined total of comps and swaps
    return (comp + lcomp + rcomp, swap + lswap + rswap)
    # base case
  return (0,0)
        
''' Function to print an array '''
def printArray(arr, size):
    
    for i in range(size):
        print(arr[i], end = " ")
    print()

# Driver code

arr = [2,8,7,1,3,5,6,4]
n = len(arr)
quicksort(arr, 0, n - 1)
print("Sorted array:")
printArray(arr, n)
```

I was expecting it to print (15,9) but instead I get errors.

Comment: What is `partition()`?

Comment: partition() is the method used to find the pivot for quicksort. I forgot to include it in the original post, just updated it.

Comment: `(lcomp, lswap) = quicksort(A, lo, p)` should be `... quicksort(A, lo, p-1)`. See the pseudocode implementation on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme

Comment: It appears that `lo >= 0 and hi >= 0 and lo < hi` is always true, so you never fall through to the base case.  When would you expect `lo >= 0` to be false?  When would you expect `hi >= 0` to be false?  When would you expect `lo < hi` to be false?